# cant delete commits from gitorious server installed

Tags: git, gitorious

I am trying to delete the commits from the gitorious server. Gitorious showing me some duplicate commits . How I can delete the commits from gitorious ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do a `git rebase -i HEAD~n`, where n is the number of commits in history you want to modify.

It lists all your commits in your favorite editor, where each line is a commit.
Delete the duplicate commit lines(if any), save and continue.

Do a `git push -f <remote> <branch>`

`-f`: force push (replace on server with what I am pushing, even if its fast-forward)

`<remote>`: your gitorious repository

`<branch>`: the branch you want to push. Don't give this option if you want to push all to all tracking branches

Hope this solves your problem!

Happy gitting!